Runtime checks required for FOREGROUND_SERVICE_SPECIAL_USE
I'm using foreground service special with updates for Android 14 as per Google guidelines.
On most Android 14 devices this works fine, but on certain devices I get the following exception
which I'm catching:
Non-fatal Exception: java.lang.SecurityException
Starting FGS with type specialUse callerApp=ProcessRecord{a5fde95 20787:com.myapp/u0a432} targetSDK=34 requires permissions: all of the permissions allOf=true [android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_SPECIAL_USE]

This is triggered by the following code:
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.UPSIDE_DOWN_CAKE)
{
  ServiceCompat.startForeground(this, COUNTDOWN_SERVICE_ID, notification, FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_SPECIAL_USE);
}
else
{
  startForeground(COUNTDOWN_SERVICE_ID, notification);
}

I've seen issues with other bits of code whereby I have to explicitly check for the service permission at runtime on Samsung devices even though it's granted, so I added the following:
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
{
  // start foreground service

but that hasn't fixed it.  If I check for if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_SPECIAL_USE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) then it returns false on the Android 14 devices I've tested.
For completeness my Manifest has the following:
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_SPECIAL_USE"/>

...
     <service
        android:name=".CountService"
        android:foregroundServiceType="specialUse"
        android:exported="false">
        <property
            android:name="android.app.PROPERTY_SPECIAL_USE_FGS_SUBTYPE"
            android:value="[Description of why foreground service is needed]" />
        </service>


Google explicitly says there are no runtime checks needed for FGS specialUse.  Anyone know what's missing?

I've tracked down my error, which was related to the build system using different product flavors.  For one of my product flavors I hadn't added the SPECIAL_USE permission.  After adding it, I can confirm that the runtime check now passes.
android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_SPECIAL_USE

